# Error running '2to3': CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I am trying to convert a huge amount of Python2 codes into Python3. I read about how to use 2to3 tool and I imported the tool from the PyCharm itself by creating an external tool as the screenshot.

[image]

For running it I right clicked on the python file>External Tools>2to3 which I keep getting this error.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add the error message you're getting? We cannot see it in the screenshots.

Comment: Hi, thank you! 
i cant take screenshot as it goes away once I press any keys.
here is the full error message:
8:41 AM Error running '2to3': Cannot run program "C:\Users\kesnaashari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Tools\scripts\2to3.py" (in directory "C:\Users\kesnaashari\AppData\Local\Temp\test.py"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application